# How can i close a view from view model in mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

Iam using WPF with MVVM pattern. I want to close a window from viewmodel . I tried to use solutions of some previous problems but it is not working.

here is my code :

ViewModel:

```
//Defining commands    
public RelayCommand SaveAddBankCommand { get; private set; }

//Constructor
        public AddBankVM()
        {
            //Initializing Commands
            SaveAddBankCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveAddBank); 
        }

//Commands methods
        public void SaveAddBank(object parameter)
        {
            new Banks().AddBank(this.BankName, _Status, System.Convert.ToDouble(Credit), this.Notes);
            new Done("Bank has been added successfully.");

            //here i want to close the window.

        }
```

view class:

```
public partial class AddBankView : Window
    {
        public AddBankView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var addBankVM = new AddBankVM();
            this.DataContext = addBankVM;
        }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this.  You need to provide some code to show us why you want to do this.  Then we can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question . You can take a look on my code.

Comment: You do have an instance of your window in your ViewModel, right, so just do `yourWindow.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Here is one way of doing it:

In the view model...

```
    //Commands methods
    public void SaveAddBank()
    {
        new Banks().AddBank(this.BankName, _Status, System.Convert.ToDouble(Credit), this.Notes);
        new Done("Bank has been added successfully.");

        //here i want to close the window.
        CloseWindowEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler CloseWindowEvent;
```

In the code behind initialization...

```
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new AddBankVM();
        (DataContext as AddBankVM).CloseWindowEvent += CommandBench_CloseWindowEvent;
```

Finally the event handler in the code behind...

```
    private void CommandBench_CloseWindowEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Conceptually what is happening is that the view model is sending an event to the window to close itself.

I suspect the MVVM style police will have some issues with this approach.  Let's see if we hear from them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to introduce the interface:

```
public interface IClosable
{
    void Close();
}
```

Then, the **only thing you need to change in code-behind** is to specify that the window implements `IClosable`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IClosable
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
    <Button Width="50"
            Height="20"
            Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            Content="Close" />
```

The ViewModel:

```
    #region Commands
    public DelegateCommand<IClosable> CloseCommand => new DelegateCommand<IClosable>(Close, CanClose);

    private bool CanClose(IClosable parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void Close(IClosable parameter)
    {
        var closable = parameter as IClosable;
        if (closable != null)
        {
            closable.Close();
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use an EventTigger, or behavior, or attached behavior, but it's less straightforward, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

At this link you will find an excellent mechanism for opening and closing dialog from viewmodel.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqKaV4d4PXg